# Illegal question mark character in path during MSBuild

Tags: jenkins, .net-core, msbuild

I am setting up our first .NET Core build on our Jenkins server. I run the build with MSBuild and it's failing with this error:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish\build\netstandard1.0\ Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.targets(84,5):
>   error MSB4184: The expression
>   "[System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath(E:\Jenkins\home\workspace\XXX\XXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXXX\XXX.XXXXXXXXXXX.build-and-deploy\API\API\obj\Development?\netcoreapp2.2\PubTmp)"
>   cannot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path.
>   [E:\Jenkins\home\workspace\XXX\XXXXXXX\XXXXXXXXXXX\XXX.XXXXXXXXXXX.build-and-deploy\API\API\API.csproj]

I can see the illegal character in the path (it's the ? after Development) but I'm not sure how it's getting there or what I can do about it. I run my MSBuild command with the following parameters:

> msbuild.exe" MapCore.sln /t:restore /p:PublishDirectory="__publish"
>   /p:DeployOnBuild=True;PublishProfile=Jenkins;Configuration=Development

The MS Build version is  16.0.461+g6ff56ef63c and builds work fine from Visual Studio 2017 on my PC. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you call MsBuild per `bat` or `sh` command?

Comment: With a bat command

Comment: Make sure there are no hidden characters like a hard space or something on the end of your line in Jenkins. Maybe an extra hidden character at the end after 'Development'.

Comment: IIRC you have to escape specific chars like `\\`as well

Comment: @JAZ You were close, the invalid character wasn't in the build command but it was in another place in my Jenkins script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. I suspected that there was an invisible character in my project configuration somewhere but after looking in the .csproj and searching the entire source for references to the Development configuration I didn't find any places where it was followed by a special character. My Groovy build script in Jenkins uses WebDeploy to deploy a WebDeploy package created by MSBuild to our servers. Typically MSDeploy packages are created based on a publish profile in the \Properties\PublishProfiles folder. In order to make setting up deployments for our many apps easier our build script will create a publish profile file based on some default settings if it does not find an existing publish profile file. **I noticed in the Jenkins pipeline editor a tofu character highlighted in red after the < LastUsedBuildConfiguration > property of the publish profile. After I removed that character the error went away.**